# How do I move a mysql installation from an old ubuntu install to a new one

Tags: mysql

The machine died, but I have the drive, but I can't exactly export the databases because there's no machine to run mysql on.

I have a new machine with a ubuntu 10.10 install (the older was was 9.10) and I would be happy to just copy /var/lib/mysql over but when I tried to restart mysql after copying the directory tree of, I got a 
init: mysql post-start process (1511) terminated with status 1

Is there an easy way to move the installation without having to unload and load all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the file permissions. What is the exact error that is in the .err file in /var/lib/mysql?

Comment: the tipoff here was that there was a mysql/err* file. I was looking in syslog. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar but with postgresql database. I copied the data files from one machine to another. Then, I got an error when trying to start the database server.

Later, I found out that the reason was different hardware. One machine has 32-bit system installed, but the other has 64-bit system.

Check your hardware specs for both machines. You may have something similar.
Also, check the files/folders permissions.

Comment: good to know, it's the same machine actually. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Copying the database files over should work - are you sure you set the files to the correct owner and chmod? MySQL is quite picky about this - you need to use chmod 600 on all DB files and have the mysql user as the owner.